# Django: Getting data from different database

Tags: django

I want to select data from a database table that is not part of my Django project. I added the database connection info to the settings file and I can do raw sql queries against it to pull the data. However, I would like to create a model for that table and be able to access the data as I would any other Django model data.

Is this possible? I can find any documentation on that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Django: Multiple Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) page contains good information on this topic. After you have configured your databases in settings.py, you can use `.using()` to specify the database you wish to query.

Examples from the documentation:

```
>>> # This will run on the 'default' database.
>>> Author.objects.all()

>>> # So will this.
>>> Author.objects.using('default').all()

>>> # This will run on the 'other' database.
>>> Author.objects.using('other').all()
```

Comment: What is Author then? Author model is not defined in models.py.

Comment: `Author` in this case is a placeholder for any object you wish to query. I simply copied the example from the documentation at the linked page. You can use any object.

Comment: Can you tell me how to execute raw queries like this? Ex:Author.objects.using('other').raw("Select * from table1")

Comment: For query purposes i recommend the use of 'Database Routers'. However, this is a very nice approach to create a classmethod in any model to copy data between databases. ;)

Answer (score 4):

sure, you just have to use

```
SomeObject.objects.using('database_name').all()
```

to do your queries